# find upper case strings in SQL record or in Python

Tags: python, sql, uppercase

I need to find, in SQL or Python, the words inside a string that are written in upper case latters, if they are exist.

For example, for the string: 'My name is NOA' it would return NOA.

The long way I thought about is to use the ascii value:
if 64 < chr(i) < 91
    if 64 < chr(i+1) < 91
....

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`string_split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx) for that.

Suppose you have this table:

```
create table phrases (
    phrase varchar(200)
);

insert into phrases values ('My name is NOA');
```

Then you can write:

```
select      phrase, value as uppercase_word
from        phrases
cross apply string_split(phrase, ' ')
where       upper(value) = value
```

With the given sample data it will return:

```
phrase         | uppercase_word
---------------+---------------
My name is NOA | NOA
```

Make sure to take note of this information in the documentation:

> The `STRING_SPLIT` function is available only under compatibility level 130. If your database compatibility level is lower than 130, SQL Server will not be able to find and execute `STRING_SPLIT` function. You can change a compatibility level of database using the following command: `ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130`